# DisplayNameFor not displaying Data MVC 5

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

As the subject says, DisplayNameFor is not displaying my data - However, TextboxFor does ?? Why ??

I have added My `Controller`(with the Method being called), `Model`(With a part of the properties as to not flood the page too much and so you get the idea of what my model looks like) and my `View`.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Controller:

public ActionResult ProjectInformation(ProjectDetailsViewModels model, int ProjectID)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var PIVM = new ProjectInformationViewModel();

        using (RexusTradingEntities RTE = new RexusTradingEntities())
        {
            var ProjectDropDownList = (from PI in RTE.ProjectInformations.ToArray()
                               orderby PI.Project_Name
                               select new SelectListItem
                               {
                                   Text = PI.Project_Name.ToString(),
                                   Value = PI.pkiProjectID.ToString(),
                                   Selected = true
                               }).ToArray();
            //For DropDownList
            PIVM.SelectedProjectID = ProjectID;

            //Adding LIST for DropDownList
            PIVM.ProjectList = ProjectDropDownList;

            var ProjectData = from PIV in RTE.ProjectInformations
                              where PIV.pkiProjectID == ProjectID
                              select new
                              {
                                  PIV.Designer_Name,
                                  PIV.Project_Name,
                                  PIV.Project_Type,
                                  PIV.Pump_Head,
                                  PIV.Reservoir_Start_Height,
                                  PIV.Reservoir_Discharge_Height,
                                  PIV.Fluid_Type,
                                  PIV.Flow_Rate,
                                  PIV.Filling_Velocity,
                                  PIV.Gravitational_Acceleration,
                                  PIV.Temperature,
                                  PIV.Elevation_Vacuum_Pressure,
                                  PIV.Pipe_Material,
                                  PIV.Estimated_Pipe_Rupture,
                                  PIV.Pipe_Absolute_Roughness,
                                  PIV.Pipe_Absolute_Roughness_Override,
                                  PIV.Allowable_Negative_Differential_Pressure,
                                  PIV.Air_Valve_Maximum_Spacing,
                                  PIV.Standardise_AirValve_Size,
                                  PIV.Standardise_Air_Valve_Pressure_Class
                              };

            //ProjectInformation PIV = new ProjectInformation();
            foreach (var pd in ProjectData)
            {
                PIVM.Designer_Name = pd.Designer_Name;
                PIVM.Project_Name = pd.Project_Name;
                PIVM.Project_Type = pd.Project_Type;
                PIVM.Pump_Head = Convert.ToDecimal(pd.Pump_Head);
                PIVM.Reservoir_Start_Height = Convert.ToDecimal(pd.Reservoir_Start_Height);
                PIVM.Reservoir_Discharge_Height = Convert.ToDecimal(pd.Reservoir_Discharge_Height);
                PIVM.Fluid_Type = pd.Fluid_Type;
                PIVM.Flow_Rate = Convert.ToDecimal(pd.Flow_Rate);
                PIVM.Filling_Velocity = Convert.ToDecimal(pd.Filling_Velocity);
                PIVM.Gravitational_Acceleration = Convert.ToDecimal(pd.Gravitational_Acceleration);
                PIVM.Temperature = Convert.ToDecimal(pd.Temperature);
                PIVM.Elevation_Vacuum_Pressure = Convert.ToDecimal(pd.Elevation_Vacuum_Pressure);
                PIVM.Pipe_Material = pd.Pipe_Material;
                PIVM.Estimated_Pipe_Rupture = Convert.ToDecimal(pd.Estimated_Pipe_Rupture);
                PIVM.Pipe_Absolute_Roughness = Convert.ToDecimal(pd.Pipe_Absolute_Roughness);
                PIVM.Pipe_Absolute_Roughness_Override = Convert.ToDecimal(pd.Pipe_Absolute_Roughness_Override);
                PIVM.Allowable_Negative_Differential_Pressure = pd.Allowable_Negative_Differential_Pressure;
                PIVM.Air_Valve_Maximum_Spacing = Convert.ToDecimal(pd.Air_Valve_Maximum_Spacing);
                PIVM.Standardise_AirValve_Size = Convert.ToDecimal(pd.Standardise_AirValve_Size);
                PIVM.Standardise_Air_Valve_Pressure_Class = Convert.ToDecimal(pd.Standardise_Air_Valve_Pressure_Class);
            }


            //PIVM.fkUserID =
            //PIVM.DateTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;

        }

        return View(PIVM);
   }
```

My Model :

```
Model:

public class ProjectInformationViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int pkiProjectID { get; set; }
    //Basic Information       
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Designer Name:")]
    public string Designer_Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Project Name:")]
    public string Project_Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Project Type:")]
    public string Project_Type { get; set; }
}
```

My view is below :

```
View:

@model AirFlo_Size_Programme.Models.ProjectInformationViewModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Project Information";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
//SelectListItem[] DesignerList = ViewBag.DesignerList;
SelectListItem[] ProjectList = ViewBag.ProjectList;
}

<h2 style="text-align:center">@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ProjectInformation", "ProjectInformation"))
{

<div>
<hr />
<h4 style="font-style:italic">Basic Information</h4>
<hr />

<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Project_Name)
    </dt>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Designer_Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Designer_Name, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "true" })
    </dt>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Project_Type)
    </dt>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Pump_Head)
    </dt>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Reservoir_Start_Height)
    </dt>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Reservoir_Discharge_Height)
    </dt>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fluid_Type)
    </dt>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Flow_Rate)
    </dt>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Filling_Velocity)
    </dt>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gravitational_Acceleration)
    </dt>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Temperature)
    </dt>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Elevation_Vacuum_Pressure)
    </dt>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Pipe_Material)
    </dt>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Estimated_Pipe_Rupture)
    </dt>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Pipe_Absolute_Roughness)
    </dt>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Pipe_Absolute_Roughness_Override)
    </dt>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Allowable_Negative_Differential_Pressure)
    </dt>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Air_Valve_Maximum_Spacing)
    </dt>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Standardise_AirValve_Size)
    </dt>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Standardise_Air_Valve_Pressure_Class)
    </dt>
</dl>
</div>
 }
<p>
     @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.pkiProjectID }) |
     @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
 </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DisplayNameFor` is for labels; it should have the property name such as `Project_Name` as the output unless you have a `DisplayNameAttribute` on the property in your model. If you want to display the property *values*, you want `DisplayFor`.

Comment: Im pretty new to MVC so im not sure im following so well ..I want to display my data in Labels? I have added a portion of my Model to the page so you can see what my model looks like.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to display?  When you say "data" I assume you mean the *value* of the property.

Comment: Ah I understand what you mean. I just didnt understand the actual use for it. Thanks! DisplayNameFor is to display the Name of the field and DisplayFor will display the actual value.